# Regex- Pattern to match a recurring string

Tags: java, regex

I want a pattern to match "+-+-+-+-+-.......",the "+-" can occur as many times,but they should be together...not like"+++--+---"

I tried "[+-]+",but it doesn't specifies that + and - are consecutive

Comment: In the future, put some real effort in to self-solve. regex101.com is a terrific resource for trialing regex patterns. This is a horribly basic regex question. I am first, surprised that this question wasn't downvoted to oblivion, and second, that two people found the answer helpful. When someone answers your question, don't just thank them -- award the answer the green tick so that your question is deemed resolved. If it doesn't quite work for some of your possible inputs (like `-+`) then you will need to clarify your question with additional samples to test against.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets (`[]`) specify a character class. What you instead want is to use a non-capturing group:

```
(?:\+-)+
```

You can of couse make it a capturing group `(\+-)+` if you want to *well* capture it all.

Comment: What does ?:\ mean

Comment: `()` specifies a capture group, adding the `?:` tells it to be a non-capturing group.

Comment: @PrateekKalra at least do the poster the courtesy of googling "non capturing group".

Comment: Why +2 for answer,and nothing for the question?Just asking

Comment: @PrateekKalra because the question shows a lack of research, not enough to warrant downvotes (you did post your single attempt), but a lack nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following samples:

```
+++--+---
-+-+-
-+-+-+
-+-+-+-
------
++++++
+-+-+-
+-+-+-+
+-+-+-+-
--++--++-
++--++--+
+-5
-+-A
```

**Vallentin's pattern has no anchors and will match anything inside the string.** `(?:\+-)+`

Can the string end on the same character it starts with?

if not, change it to:

`^(?:\+-)+$`

if it can:

For "+ only starts":
Access full match result using pattern: `^(\+(?:-|$))+$`

For possibility of "+ and - starts":
Access full match result using pattern: `^(?:([+-])(?!\1))+$`

Compare all three patterns @ this [demo that defaults to Vallentin's pattern](https://regex101.com/r/LkBBWI/1).

Comment: @PrateekKalra  How is your implementation?  I have thought a bit deeper about your case and I have some concerns.  Please read my answer and switch the green tick if my answer is "better".

Comment: OP already specified the pattern was `+-` and `+++--+---` wouldn't be valid. If OP needed the start/end of the line, then adding those won't be a problem. Additionally consider that say `String`'s `matches()` enforces that by default. Point being that we don't know what OP is using.

Comment: @Vallentin Don't be offended.  More times than not, first time posters do not fully understand the issue that they are asking about AND don't lay out all of the necessary information in their question.  Not only did I want to elaborate on the issue with some potential issues for this question, I also wanted to inform future readers so that there were fewer copy-paste issues.  It would be a better question if it included the actual code being used.